# Cannot create relationship: Error:Missing index on column(s)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make relation on 2 tables in database designer.

I am using relationship tool. Below are the steps followed:

1. I clicked on the ID in table `lekar`.
2. Then I click on `lekar` column in the next table.
3. Pressed OK.

It throws the below error, what is the problem ?

```
Error: Missing index on column(s).
```

I added ID column so it will have indexing, but it still does not work.

[image: dberr]

Answer (score 1):

Ahoj Hynku,

zkus tam přidat CONSTRAINT `id` nebo/a FOREIGN KEY`id`s referencí na druhou tabulku s 'Id' sloupcem.

Hi Hynek,

You can try add CONSTRAINT `id` or/and FOREIGN KEY`id` with refernece on second table with 'Id' column.